# Space between before pseudoelement and window

Tags: css

I have before element which show's line bottom.
Is this possible to add margin right to this before element that it will one space for example 20 pixels in every screen sizes.

Right now as you can see I'm adding space from right with manipulating width property .In here this space didn't show'n.

Please help.

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  
}
.link_more {
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1
}

.link_more a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .link_more a {
        margin-right:0
    }
}

.link_more a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width: 9.6%;
    top: 25px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .link_more a:before {
        width:16%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .link_more a:before {
        width:10%
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .link_more a:before {
        width:9.6%
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
    .link_more a:before {
        width:calc(100% - 73.7vw)
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .main_wallpaper .main_content .link_more a:before {
        content:"";
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        width: 8.6%;
        top: 25px
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="link_more">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">more</a>
</div>
```

Comment: probably because you have margin-left auto so your div is being pushed to the right instead of having a gap on the right, but it's not exactly clear what the question is

Comment: don't use width but use right/left

Comment: @Pete the question is how to add space to before element from right

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'll try ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want right margin of 20px, You can use right:20px; instead of width

```
.link_more a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #000;
    right:20px;
    position:relative;
}

.link_more a:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    top: 25px
    right:20px;
}
```